# Eight seconds after powering on, my phone goes dark and becomes unresponsive. What can I do?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, screen, troubleshooting, shutdown

I have a Samsung Galaxy S Relay. (This is kind of like a Samsung Galaxy S III plus a slide-out physical keyboard.) It's running stock Android 4.1.2, rooted using TWRP and SuperSU.

I was using Spotify yesterday when things started to go wrong. Soon, I saw only blackness and the phone's buttons stopped working — even the power button was useless. Also, when I connected my phone to my computer using a USB cable, the computer's `lsusb` command reported that there were no USB devices plugged in, and the `dmesg` command indicated that there had been nary a peep from the phone. Maybe the phone was off.

I had no choice but to remove and reinsert the phone's battery.

When I reinsert the battery, the phone seems to start working again, but only for eight seconds. I can take advantage of these eight seconds in different ways:

- I can attempt a normal boot. I see the "Samsung" logo screen, then the Galaxy S Relay logo screen, then everything goes dark.
- If I press certain buttons, I can enter Download Mode very briefly before the screen goes dark.
- If I press other buttons, I can ask the phone to enter recovery mode. I see "Samsung" and "Recovery booting...." before everything goes dark.
- If I connect the charging cable and the battery at the same time, I see the usual graphic telling me to wait for the [charging status display software](http://forums.androidcentral.com/general-help-how/327784-how-do-you-read-android-power-off-screen-battery-charging-not.html) to load and start itself. But the screen goes dark, and the charging status display never appears.

Once the screen goes dark, it stays dark. Even if I hold the power button down for 30 seconds, then let go for a bit, then hold it down for another 30 seconds, nothing happens. If I want to make the phone work for another eight seconds, I must first remove and reinsert the battery.

I don't think the battery is empty. My multimeter says that the battery is at about 3.9 volts. For a lithium-ion battery, 3.9 volts means "90% full".

What troubleshooting steps can I try next?

[Edit: This post is basically a verbatim copy of [a Reddit post of mine](https://www.reddit.com/r/AndroidQuestions/comments/5dkf3h/eight_seconds_after_powering_on_my_phone_goes/).]

Answer (score 1):

I have owned several Samsung galaxy devices (including an S3 which is somewhat similar to your phone). Often I find that the battery becomes faulty after 2 years of usage. The symptoms you mention also sounds like battery related problems. The key giveaway is that you unable to sustain download mode before your screen goes dark.

**Troubleshooting**

1. Try replacing the battery. This will eliminate the possibility of a
   faulty battery. After replacing the battery, see whether your phone
   will stay on for more than a few seconds.
2. If you unable to acquire a second battery,  try booting your phone whilst in the charger. It should be noted that using the phone
   whilst charging isn't usually a good idea, however for
   troubleshooting it should be fine.
3. Check your charger, wires should not be frayed or worn. Worn
   chargers can affect your phone's battery.